# I can't see my service inside services page. TopShelf

Tags: c#, topshelf

I have a console application that reads SQL server data, processes that data, and logs that process's result to another SQL server table. I want to convert that  `console application` to `windows service` with using `Topshelf`.
Here is my configuration class:

```
    internal static class ConfigureService
    {
        internal static void Configure()
        {
            HostFactory.Run(configure =>
            {
                configure.Service<MyService>(service =>
                {
                    service.ConstructUsing(s => new MyService());
                    service.WhenStarted(s => s.Start());
                    service.WhenStopped(s => s.Stop());
                });
                //Setup Account that window service use to run.  
                configure.RunAsLocalSystem();
                configure.SetServiceName("MyWindowServiceWithTopshelf");
                configure.SetDisplayName("MyWindowServiceWithTopshelf");
                configure.SetDescription("My .Net windows service with Topshelf");
            });
        }
    }
```

and my service class:

```
public class MyService
{

    public void Start()
    {
        Operation operation = new Operation();

        operation.Zamanlayıcı();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        // write code here that runs when the Windows Service stops.  
    }
}
```

Code works fine with this classes inside console application.And ı can see the inside console application that service started successfully.But ı cant see that service inside services page.And this is what ı have when ı install service

> installutil winservicebackupwork1.exe
>   Microsoft (R) .NET Framework
>   Installation utility Version 4.7.2046.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of
>   the log file for the
>   C:-----------------WinServiceBackUpWork1\WinServiceBackUpWork1\bin\Debug\winservicebackupwork1.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   C:-----------------------\WinServiceBackUpWork1\WinServiceBackUpWork1\bin\Debug\winservicebackupwork1.InstallLog.
>   Installing assembly
>   'C:-------------------------\WinServiceBackUpWork1\WinServiceBackUpWork1\bin\Debug\winservicebackupwork1.exe'.
>   Affected parameters are:    logtoconsole =    logfile =
>   C:-------------------------------\WinServiceBackUpWork1\WinServiceBackUpWork1\bin\Debug\winservicebackupwork1.InstallLog
>   assemblypath =
>   C:------------------------\WinServiceBackUpWork1\WinServiceBackUpWork1\bin\Debug\winservicebackupwork1.exe
>
> The Install phase completed successfully, and the Commit phase is
>   beginning. See the contents of the log file for the
>   C:---------------------------\WinServiceBackUpWork1\WinServiceBackUpWork1\bin\Debug\winservicebackupwork1.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   C:---------------------------------\WinServiceBackUpWork1\WinServiceBackUpWork1\bin\Debug\winservicebackupwork1.InstallLog.
>   Committing assembly
>   'C:--------------------------------\WinServiceBackUpWork1\WinServiceBackUpWork1\bin\Debug\winservicebackupwork1.exe'.
>   Affected parameters are:    logtoconsole =    logfile =
>   C:----------------------------\WinServiceBackUpWork1\WinServiceBackUpWork1\bin\Debug\winservicebackupwork1.InstallLog
>   assemblypath =
>   C:---------------------------\WinServiceBackUpWork1\WinServiceBackUpWork1\bin\Debug\winservicebackupwork1.exe
>
> The Commit phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed.

However according to my research, When I install service, it should print differently and I don't know how to fix.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-windows-service-in-net-with-topshelf/ This is my source. Please help.

Comment: seems ok to me. have you tried refreshing services page?

Comment: Yeah ı tried hundred times.Everything seems fine except ı cant see that inside services page.

Comment: I dont know the reason but when ı tried to install with powershell it worked. I can start service from services page. But this time ı can't log the result to SQL server. Probably need to permission code inside my codeblock. Still waiting for a respond why ı can't install with CMD.